# Can I use the flowplayer in Production server is it Free

Tags: html, video, flowplayer

I am using the below URL to play videos in my site

http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf

Is it free and legal to use it in production.

Comment: You could read [this page](http://flowplayer.org/download/) and find it out by yourself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes i have gone through this site

[FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org)

And find out that It can use under The GNU General Public License (GNU is a free, copyleft license for software and other kinds of works). And it can hosted it in live server but the copy right protected and the logo will always be there in the player. If you want to customize the logo you have to buy it from the above site.